# Getting wikipedia links to company pages

Tags: wikipedia-api

I have a list of companies that I would like to get the wikipedia page's of. Does wikipedia offer an api or a way of doing this so I don't have to go and search each on individually?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia does have an API, which is documented at http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API. You can also export a list of pages (by title) using [Special:Export](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aExport). But if you are intending to download a large number of articles, you would be better served with a [database download](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API